# Is it experimentally verified that elementary/fundamental particles don't have temperature?

Tags: particle-physics, temperature

Temperature is meaningless if talking about elementary particle i.e. we can't say that an electron is hotter or cooler.... But is this experimentally verified? Because theoretically it is arguable.

Comment: Well, can you count any allowed energy states for the particle? Because that's the underlying parameter required to be able to calculate temperature/entropy

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243512

Comment: Yeah thanks for providing....

Comment: "Because theoretically it is arguable" - only if you first come up with a sensible definition of a temperature of an elementary particle; without that, no one can know what to experimentally verify or how. What I mean is, if you're talking about the usual thermodynamic idea of temperature, then the notion of the temperature of an elementary particle is meaningless *by definition*. It's like asking: "in a sweater, what's the thread pattern in the holes between the threads?" You'd have to find a way to extend that concept in a meaningful way. See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/128872

Comment: @SwayamJha Temperature is nothing but how much particles in an object move. If they're very still, then the object is cold, and if they are excited then the object is hot. What do you mean by temperature? This article might answer your question: https://www.quantamagazine.org/quantum-correlations-reverse-thermodynamic-arrow-of-time-20180402/

Comment: But we are comparing temperature with heat i.e. temperature of an electron is meaningless because "hot" or "cold" electrons doesn't exist! But what if for fundamental particles, the effect of temperature is not making them cool or hot something different.... Because I have searched recently, that, Relativistic Thermodynamics is a puzzle and it might be because our fundamental definitions of the statiscal properties are wrong?.... What ya'll think?